# Error implementing facebook like button

Tags: html, facebook

This is my HTML and JS code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css" /> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/foofighters?ref=ts&fref=ts" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And as a result I get this:

[image: Screen shot]

I follow the Facebook documentation properly, I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a validation test on your code. It's invalid.

Remove the xml and try with HTML and later go on with XHTML if needed.

This will work (tested)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css" /> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/foofighters?ref=ts&fref=ts" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well let me put it live, one sec. @petko_stankoski

Comment: @petko_stankoski here you are: https://googledrive.com/host/0B-_Y5_hBrhHWQlhsRlpSY3JNODg/test.html

Comment: @petko_stankoski look at the https addition due to site being on https. Open on chrome the js console and make sure you don't get any errors that protocols don't match